# SQL insert is not working

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

Please can someone help? The code below seems to work and gives no errors, but when I check the database, it hasn't added anything. Tearing my hair out!

```
<?php
$bcode = $_GET['barcode'];
$businessid = $_GET['businessid'];
$servername = "---------";
$username = "-------"; 
$password = "-------";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO 'db741921215'.'Scans' (Barcode, Success, Business) VALUES ('".$barcode."', 'Y', '".$businessid."')"; 
$con->close();
} ?>
```

The columns in table 'Scans' is as below:

[image: Table Description]

Help is very, very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Does `$sql` return a 1 or 0 ?  Indicating a "pass" or "fail"  --  You should put an `or die()` on your `INSERT` as well to help with troubleshooting ..

Comment: Hi, what is on the code is what I used - commit? And echo $sql just shows the code INSERT INTO Scans (Barcode, Success, Business) VALUES ('-----', '-----', '-----')

Comment: You seem to be missing the step where you execute the sql statement (you define it but I don't see where it's executed. i.e. `$conn->query($sql)` ) - also, you seem to be missing a letter when closing the connection (`$con->close()`)

Comment: `$conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`  right before `$conn->close;`

Comment: Thanks guys - stupid mistakes, d'oh. Sorry I'm a beginner. Works now I've amended as per all your comments. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple things - use backticks "`" around your table name definitions, not single quotes. Also, save yourself some eye strain and use the fact that PHP interpolates variables just fine within doublequoted strings.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `db741921215`.`Scans` 
  (Barcode, Success, Business) 
  VALUES 
  ('$barcode', 'Y', '$businessid')";
```

Also - you never actual execute the query, do you?

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing the step where you execute the `sql` statement

I can see where you define it but I don't see where it's executed. i.e.

```
$conn->query($sql);
```

Also, you seem to be missing a letter when closing the connection: `$con->close()` should be `$conn->close();`